# Equivalent bitget function in R

Tags: r

Is there a function in R that performs the same operation as bitget in MatLab/Octave:

[bitget](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/bitget.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614283/converting-decimal-to-binary-in-r

Comment: Quick question, the results of the function in the questions above `paste(sapply(strsplit(paste(rev(intToBits(100))),""),`[[`,2),collapse="")` do not match the octave equivalent `bitget(100,1:30)`

Comment: Ah, I see it.  It is just reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `bitget` help page

```
Return the status of bit(s) n of unsigned integers in A the 
lowest significant bit is n = 1.

    bitget (100, 8:-1:1)
    ⇒ 0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0
```

so if you want to get the bit values for an integer in R, you can do

```
intToBits(100)[8:1]
# [1] 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 00
```

That technically returns a raw vector, so if you want just a numeric vector, do

```
as.numeric(intToBits(100)[8:1])
# [1] 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```