# Converting Decimals into Binaries

Tags: r

I have been using the following code to convert decimals into binaries, however I cannot seem to convert a decimal greater than 1069 into binary.

```
run_id = 1:1600
run_ids = as.data.frame(run_id)
run_ids$bin = 0

for (i in 1:length(x)){
  run_ids[i,2] = as.numeric(paste(rev(as.numeric(intToBits(as.numeric(run_ids[i,1])))), collapse=""))
}
```

Unfortunately the range of numbers that I want to convert goes up to 1,600.
I have tried to use as.double, as.numeric to fix the issue however these do not work.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: In your example, `x` is not defined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614283/converting-decimal-to-binary-in-r

Comment: I am able to convert up to 1600 using your code (using @RHertel correction).

Comment: The limit of `intToBits()` is 2^31-1, i.e., 2147483647.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works after a minor correction.

The desired ouput can be obtained by replacing `for(i in 1:length(x)){` with `for(i in run_id){`:

```
run_id <- 1:1600
run_ids <- as.data.frame(run_id)
run_ids$bin <- 0
for (i in run_id){
  run_ids[i,2] <- as.numeric(paste(rev(as.numeric(intToBits(as.numeric(run_ids[i,1])))), collapse=""))
}
> tail(run_ids)
#     run_id         bin
#1595   1595 11000111011
#1596   1596 11000111100
#1597   1597 11000111101
#1598   1598 11000111110
#1599   1599 11000111111
#1600   1600 11001000000
```

Comment: @user5375228 I don't see the point. You say you are not able to convert decimal greater than 1069, but your code just didn't run?

Comment: The code worked however only up to 1069. I made a couple of modifications to it to post in the forum. However my error was as RHertel pointed out with the for loop length. Works perfectly now thank you.