# Converting non-integer decimal numbers to binary

Tags: r, binary, numeric

data frame input (DF)

```
a
123.213
4343.344
3434.43255
422.45
34534
```

results required in binary (16 bits)

I have tried a function

```
intTobits
rawTobits
```

but didn't worked for me

Comment: in that case only integers were used but here we have numeric values in decimal fractions also

Comment: I don't think there is any preexisting function. You have to write your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion of *integer* decimal numbers into binary numbers is thoroughly discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6614283/4770166). Non-integer numbers are a different issue.

For the binary representation of floating point decimal numbers you can try this function:

```
floatToBin <- function(x){
  int_part <- floor(x)
  dec_part <- x - int_part
  int_bin <- R.utils::intToBin(int_part)
  dec_bin <- stringr::str_pad(R.utils::intToBin(dec_part * 2^31), 31, pad="0")
  sub("[.]?0+$", "", paste0(int_bin, ".", dec_bin)) 
}
```

Note that this function only works for **non-negative** numbers.

This is the output for the numbers indicated in the question:

```
nums <- c(123.213, 4343.344, 3434.43255, 422.45, 34534)
sapply(nums, floatToBin)
#[1] "1111011.0011011010000111001010110000001"     
#[2] "1000011110111.010110000001000001100010010011"
#[3] "110101101010.0110111010111011100110001100011"
#[4] "110100110.0111001100110011001100110011001"   
#[5] "1000011011100110"
```