# R - how to convert integer into a bit vector?

Tags: r

Given an integer, I need to convert it into a vector of n bits which correspond to the binary representation of the given integer.

Examples:

```
1 should return 0 0 0 1
2 should return 0 0 1 0
3 should return 0 0 1 1
4 should return 0 1 0 0
```

How do I achieve this in R using R libraries?

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614283/converting-decimal-to-binary-in-r `R.utils::intToBin(10)`