# R language: using binary, octal and hexdecimal literals

Tags: r

How to use binary and octal literals?

I am new in R. So, when I start to use the numbers in binary, octal and hexdecimal bases I had assumed to use the standart prefixes in the description of these literals, i.e. 0b... for binary representation, 0o... for octal and 0x...for hexdecimal. But in fact I found that I can use only hexdecimal literal like 0xFFF and other use rises the errors like "Error: unexpected symbol in "0b1010"" or Error: unexpected symbol in "0o123".

So, is there a chance to use binary or octal literals in the same way? Or, may be there are other standart mechanism to proceed with all of these bases insteed of use any functions like strtoi() or as.integer(), or sprintf(), or other third-party packages?

All versions of language and IDEs are up-to-date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Conversion to base 10

You mention the base function `strtoi()` in your question. You can use this to express hex, octal and decimal strings, but not binary: From the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strtoi.html):

> The standard C rules for choosing the base are that octal constants (prefix `0` not followed by `x` or `X`) and hexadecimal constants (prefix `0x` or `0X`) are interpreted as base 8 and 16; all other strings are interpreted as base 10.

```r
x <- c(
    "255", # 255 in base 10
    "0xFF", # 255 in hex
    "0377" # 255 in octal
)

strtoi(x)
# [1] 255 255 255
```

I don't know why `"0b"` prefixed strings were not included in this. You can still supply binary strings with no prefix, as long as you specify the base as an argument:

```r
strtoi("11111111", base = 2)
# [1] 255
```

#### Conversion from base 10

You mentioned `sprintf()` which again you can use for hex and octal but not for binary. From the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html):

> `d, i, o, x, X`: Integer value, `o` being octal, `x` and `X` being hexadecimal (using the same case for a-f as the code).

```r
# cat() is so we get real new lines rather than "\n"
cat(sprintf(
    paste(
        "Base ten: %d",
        "Hex: %x",
        "Octal: %o",
        sep = "\n"
    ),
    x, x, x
))
# Base ten: 255
# Hex: ff
# Octal: 377
```

For binary, you can use `intToBits()`. However, this returns a big-endian raw vector with many trailing zeroes, e.g.:

```r
intToBits(255)
#  [1] 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

This may not be what you want. For various methods for getting it into a more appropriate format, see [Converting decimal to binary in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6614595/12545041)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to write a couple wrapper functions of your own.  For example, to start processing character strings beginning with `0x` ,

```
if(length(grep('0x',my_data)) {
    thebase = 16
    my_data <- gsub('0x','',my_data)
    }
```

And then proceed to convert the character string as desired. I'll put in a plug for my package `bigBits` which handles numbers (in any base up to 36) of arbitrary size with full precision.  Note that baseR functions like `strtoi` and `intToBits` are limited to 32-bits IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Using the explanation of [SamR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248914/2315037) and the [Converting decimal to binary in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6614595/12545041) the answer of using the binary conversion for me is:

```
trimws(paste(rev(as.integer(intToBits(12))), collapse=""),which = "l",whitespace = "0")
```

Also, may be in convenient way be the using of R.utils library and its functions intToBit(), intToHex() and intToOct():

```
> library(R.utils)
> intToBit(12)
[1] "1100"
> intToHex(12)
[1] "c"
> intToOct(12)
[1] "14"
```